# Triple integral - incorrect boundaries?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to find the result of

$$   
\iiint\limits_{U} e^{x+y+z} \,dz\,dy\,dx
$$

where
$$
U : x \le 0,  
-x\le y \le 1,
0\le z \le -x
$$
I got the boundaries: $$ -1 \le x \le 0,\\  
0\le y \le 1,\\
0\le z \le 1
$$
And
$$   
\int\limits_{-1}^0\int\limits_{0}^{1}\int\limits_{0}^1 e^{x+y+z} \,dz\,dy\,dx = (e-1) \int\limits_{-1}^0\int\limits_{0}^{1} e^{x+y} \,dy\,dx= (e-1)^2 \int\limits_{-1}^0 e^{x} \,dx = \frac{(e-1)^3}{e} 
$$ 
But that answer is incorrect. Did I choose the wrong boundaries?

Comment: Yes you did. The boundaries you chose define a cube, but the region of integration is not a cube. The boundaries of the inner integrals have to be functions of the variables that have yet to be integrated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\mapsto -x$ so that we want to integrate
$$\iiint_{U'}e^{-x+y+z}dz\,dy\,dx$$
where $U'$ is the region defined by $x\geq0,x\leq y\leq 1,0\leq z\leq x$. This is of course equivalent to $$0\leq z\leq x\leq y\leq 1.$$ For fixed $x$ and $y$, the value of $z$ can range from $0$ to $x$. For fixed $x$, the value of $y$ can range from $x$ to $1$. Finally, $x$ ranges from $0$ to $1$. So the integral we should get is
$$\int_0^1\int_x^1\int_0^xe^{-x+y+z}dz\,dy\,dx=3-e.$$
Where you went wrong was in finding the limits of integration. In particular, the limits of integration shouldn't be constant values which denote the maximum and minimum attainable values of each variable across all possible values of the other variables as you have done, but the values of the outer variables need to be considered as given fixed values. So the question you ask when you try to find the boundaries of integration for $z$ shouldn't be, "what's the largest and smallest possible value of $z$?" It should instead be "what's the largest and smallest possible value of $z$, given that $0\leq z\leq x$ for fixed $x$?"

Comment: Is step $x↦−x$ necessary? Can I put $-x$ in the limits of these two integrals?

Comment: @Patrycja Of course you can, and you should get the same result. I only did that because I thought it made the solution nicer not to have that negative sign lying around, but it's totally unnecessary to do so.